# GoLang goSpace Get function does not work

Tags: go

I am new to Go, but I can't seem to get this code working (following this [example](https://github.com/pSpaces/goSpace-examples/blob/master/fridge/main.go)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    . "github.com/pspaces/gospace"
)

func p1(board *Space, l int) {
  mult := 1
  for i := 1; i <= l; i++ {
      mult = mult * i
  }

  t, e := board.PutP("P1", mult)
  fmt.Printf("Error 1: %v  (tuple: %v)", e, t)  // Error 1: <nil> (tuple: "P1", 120)
  
  fmt.Printf("Multiplication by process1 was placed in the tuplespace\n")
}

func p2(board *Space, k int, m int) {
  mult := 1
  for i := k; i <= m; i++ {
      mult = mult * i
  }

  t, e := board.PutP("P2", mult)
  fmt.Printf("Error 2: %v (tuple: %v)", e, t)  // Error 2: <nil> (tuple: "P2", 30240)
  
  fmt.Printf("Multiplication by process2 was placed in the tuplespace\n")
}

func p(board *Space) {
    fmt.Printf("In the P\n")

    var r1 int
    var r2 int
    
    board.Get("P1", &r1)
    fmt.Println("Process took value from p1")
    board.Get("P2", &r2)
    fmt.Println("Process took value from p2")
    fmt.Println(r1)  // 0  --> PROBLEM HERE
    fmt.Println(r2)  // 0  --> PROBLEM HERE
    
    //r := r1 * r2
    //board.Put("P", r)
    fmt.Printf("Multiplication of process1 and process2 was performed and the result was placed in the tuplespace\n")
}

func main() {
    board := NewSpace("board")
    go p1(&board, 5)
    go p2(&board, 6, 10)

    fmt.Println("Write 'start' in order to start final computation\n ")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    
    fmt.Println(board.Size())
    go p(&board)
    board.Query("done")
}
```

As I was writing this question, I kind of found a workaround:

```golang
tp, e := board.Get("P1", &r1)
fmt.Println("Process took value from p1")
fmt.Printf("Tuple: %v, Error %v\n", tp, e)  // Tuple: "P1, 120", Error <nil>
```

However, this still is not the intended way to use Get (and `r1` is still 0). I would like to get only the "value" of P1, instead of the full tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this example is buggy. Parameters to `Get()` are used to build a pattern to filter the result. So you can pass actual values or filter by type by passing pointer to variable.

You should get value from the tuple, e.g. this way: `r1 = (t.GetFieldAt(1)).(int)`

So the linked example can be fixed this way:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        . "github.com/pspaces/gospace"
)

func main() {
        fridge := NewSpace("fridge")

        // Add some stuff to the grocery list.
        fridge.Put("milk", 2)
        fridge.Put("butter", 3)

        // Retrieve one item via pattern matching.
        var item string
        var quantity int
        if t, e := fridge.Get(&item, &quantity); e == nil {
                quantity = (t.GetFieldAt(1)).(int)
                item = (t.GetFieldAt(0)).(string)
        }

        // Print the item retrieved.
        fmt.Printf("%s: (%v, %v)\n", "Grocery item", item, quantity)
}
```

Comment: Yep, this makes more sense. So, this is the only way to get items via pattern matching, right?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is the only way.